# Minimal working example how to extract current (remote) ActiveDirectory user (without HTTPS) using Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, active-directory, ldap, jndi

I am looking for a minimal working example in java and the appropriate Tomcat configuration files which allows me to extract the UserPrincipal from a client.

After reading various recipes on the topic [Tomcat and LDAP](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Tomcat%20And%20LDAP) I am still struggling with getting my Tomcat to do what I want, namely to make the client send the Active Directory information to my Tomcat server. I managed to configure, understand and test a  *BASIC AUTH* access control, adjusting the usual suspects **Tomcat/conf/server.xml** and **webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml**.

For the current LDAP user challenge, the Realm (within host-scope of **server.xml**) reads:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" debug="10"
       connectionURL="ldap://me.myserver.net:389"
       userBase="ou=Standard User,ou=Users and Groups,ou=me,dc=myserver,dc=net"
       roleSubtree="true" roleNested="false"/>
```

Within the **web.xml**, we have

```
 <security-role>
   <description>All authenticated users</description>
   <role-name>ldapAuthenticated</role-name>
 </security-role>

<security-constraint>
  <display-name>userConstraint</display-name>
  <web-resource-collection>
     <web-resource-name>LDAP Test</web-resource-name>
     <url-pattern>/ldap</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
     <role-name>ldapAuthenticated</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
  <user-data-constraint>
     <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

The essential java part is probably the following (which runs, but *currentPrincipalName* stays empty):

```
public static String ldapGroupService(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String out = "<html><body><h1>{ldapGroupService}/ldap</h1>";
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String currentPrincipalName = authentication.getName();
    out = out + "<p>The user is '" + currentPrincipalName  + "'.</p>" + "<body></html>";
    return out;
}
```

Related posts did provide Tomcat configuration, but they did not focus on the issue how to obtain a non-empty Authentification-line in the Response header (to be checked e.g. with F12 in Chrome) from the client.

- [How to configure JNDI Realm with Tomcat 7 for PKI User Certificate Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639382/how-to-configure-jndi-realm-with-tomcat-7-for-pki-user-certificate-authenticatio)
- [Java LDAP - Determine if user in a given group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570466/java-ldap-determine-if-user-in-a-given-group)
- [How to configure JNDI Realm with Tomcat 7 for PKI User Certificate Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639382/how-to-configure-jndi-realm-with-tomcat-7-for-pki-user-certificate-authenticatio)
- [External LDAP JNDI connectivity using Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26249394/external-ldap-jndi-connectivity-using-tomcat)
- [Trying to configure LDAP as JNDI Resource in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040980/trying-to-configure-ldap-as-jndi-resource-in-tomcat)